# Span ignoring image body and covers up the whole div

Tags: html, css

I've created four divs vertically aligned, the four are floated left, right, left, right respectively. Inside each div I have an image and a `<span>` defining about the image. In the first div (aligned:left), I have image on left, while text (span) is on right, I had done this just by floating the image in div to right, and setting the `<span>` to `display:block`, **this** automatically aligns my image to left and text to right, inside the division. Similarly in the next `<div>`, I have aligned the image to right of the div and span was already set to `display:block`, but this doesn't work, the `text-align:center` property centers the `<span>` considering the whole div, and it comes over the image, instead of aligning itself to center of the left up space in the div. **Which is the main issue I'm having**. Continuing to third div, which is again aligned left, and works perfectly with same attributes, now for the fourth div, I'm surprised that the fourth div, which is aligned right(like second one), works perfectly fine, the `float:right` on image, aligns it to right of the div, and text is aligned center in the remaining space on the right.
Second and fourth divs are similar, i.e floated right, with image on right and text on left, they use same CSS classes, same attributes, the only difference is they that the fourth occur a little later in my html and it works fine, but second doesn't.
Here is the code for my second div

```
<div class="din">
<img src="d1.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d2.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="d3.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d4.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<img src="d5.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d6.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="d7.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d8.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<img src="d9.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d10.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="d11.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="d12.jpg" class="sp2 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<span class="inside-text">Your living style matters,<br /> a better<br />   
living room</span>
</div>
```

I know these are more than one images, but they are displayed one-by-one using animation and JavaScript.

CSS for this div

```
.din{
border:2px solid #000;
width:600px;
height:210px;
margin-top:-4px;
margin-right:30px;
float:right;
}
.sp2{
float:right;
}
.inside-text{
display:block;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
margin:15px;
line-height:2;
color:grey;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Class `.lan` is for animation, posting it anyway.

```
.lan{
animation:fading 5s infinite
}
```

Note:The `sp2` class is used in JavaScript, so I could not use it in another div, so I created a similar class called `sp4` for fourth div, here is the code for the div

```
<div class="din">
<img src="w1.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w2.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="w3.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w4.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<img src="w5.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w6.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="w7.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w8.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<img src="w9.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w10.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px"/>
<img src="w11.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height="210px" />
<img src="w12.jpg" class="sp4 lan" width="400px" height=210px" />
<span class="inside-text">Your living style matters,<br /> a better<br /> 
living room</span>
</div>
```

It's CSS

```
.sp4{
float:right;
}
```

This division works fine.
I know I can align the image to the right using `margin-left` property, but the image fades in and out **over** the text, how can I place text on left, apart from image. I even tried giving a new class to images of both divs and set the property `float:right` in that class, it was still working on 4th but not on 2nd. 
I've attached screenshots of both divs.
I know I wrote way too much, I just did this to be clear.

[Image of second div, the one causing problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxjc8.png)

[Image of fourth div, looks perfect, this is how I want the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0seCe.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As the given code doesn't show the same as your screen shots, you need to provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue, or else we have no chance other than start guessing

Comment: What he said. You mention the sp2 class is "used in JavaScript", implying that sp4 is not, so there is obviously a difference, but you never show the JavaScript causing this difference!

Comment: Also, you have typos, missing quotes, as evident by the syntax highlighting being off, so you might want to run your HTML through the W3C validator.

Comment: @MrLister Both divs have their separate JavaScript classes, sp2 & sp4, these both classes have same property (float) in CSS. They are used in JavaScript for slider (displaying on at a time).

Comment: @LGSon I didn't actually understand what you meant, the code I provided gives the output in the screen shots.

Comment: Not for us, so we will be able to troubleshoot...for that you need to post a working code sample (preferable Stack snippet, else Fiddle) as when I try your code it does not render the same output

Comment: @LGSon This is the JavaScript code for both divs, it is totally same, except for the names of variables and the class name for the div, obviously. Hope this helps.

`<script>

var myIndex = 0;

carousel();

function carousel() {

var i2;

var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("sp2");

for (i2 = 0; i2 < x2.length; i2++) {

x2[i2].style.display = "none";  

}

myIndex++;

if (myIndex > x2.length) {myIndex = 1}    

x2[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

setTimeout(carousel, 4000);    

}

</script>`

Comment: Why should we try create a working snippet? ... It is _you_ that should do that, and it should be within the question, not as a comment.